# opencv opengl drawing on a frame

Tags: opengl, opencv

How can I use both Opencv and OpenGl to draw some 3D shape onto a Mat frame ? The scenario is simple I am grabbing some frames ( cv::Mat) and I would like to visualise them with some 3D cool target arrows like this ---> target <---. Any ideas on how to do that? What would be a good reference to search for ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly use latest OpenCV version, or use the version which comes with Qt support. Make sure that you install OpenCV with Qt support, if you are building yourself then build with Qt support. Next go to this link http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/qt_new_functions.html#setopengldrawcallback
A single function will let you draw on the top of the image using a callback function.